# Intellisense showing false errors, cannot "go to definition" (Visual Studio 2013)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

I am finding that on my computer, Intellisense often fails (doesn't appear) and that I often get false errors (red underlines) in my code when my code actually compiles and works OK.

Typically, the error is on a using directive and when you hover it says "The type or namespace name 'X' could not be found". However namespace X is defined within the current project.

If I compile, the errors temporarily disappear until I change the code, then they come back a couple of seconds later.

I've tried cleaning and rebuilding the project, deleting my Visual Studio project and global settings, deleting the bin/obj folders etc. Everything works fine in VS 2012.

What could be making intellisense misbehave like this?

Comment: I've had similar (but not so severe or prolonged) behavior when a reference cannot be resolved.  Perhaps a versioning problem?

Comment: Exactly same problem here, only manifests for c++/cli project references. Also problem first appeared on Release, now both Release and Debug configs. It seams that problems appears as solution gets larger. How many project do you have? I am at 165 and now Debug started to give me false errors. I think i had about 140 when problems started on Release.

Answer (score 0):

have you recently added some extensions to File Extension? if yes, then go to Tools> Options> Text Editor> File Extension, and then clear all extensions you didn't add, then close the solution and open it again